# C++ I'm trying to end this infinite loop to find even numbers between 0 and the users entered value

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to find the even numbers between 0 and the users entered value like 500 for example. I can only use for and if loops.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int value = 0;


    //Ask user to enter a number between 0 and 501
    cout << "Please enter a value between 0 and 501: \n";
    cin >> value;


    if (value < 0 || value > 501)
    {
    cout << "ERROR! The value you entered is out of range!\n";
    cout << "Please enter a value between 0 and 501\n";
    cin >> value;
    }
        for (value = 0; value > 0 || value < 501; value++)
        {
            if (value % 2 == 0)
            {
            cout << "The even numbers are: " << value << endl;
            }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you think of a number which is less than or equal to 0 and simultaneously greater than or equal to 501? Because both of those conditions must be true in order for the `for` loop to terminate, since only one of these condition must be false in order for the `for` loop to continue (that's how `||` works).

Comment: Everything below 0 and above 501 is not allowed in the program. I'm new to this so I might be reading your question wrong sorry if i do.

Comment: You check the bounds the first time the user enters a number, but what about the second time?

Comment: Let me restate my comment: this `for` loop will only terminate when the loop number is simultaneously less than or equal to 0 and greater than or equal to 501. This is not possible, according to some fundamental laws of quantum mechanics of our shared universe, and this is why you have an infinite loop. You need to fix your loop's condition logic.

Comment: Ahhh ok I got what your saying now. I will get to fixing that now. Thank you Sam

Comment: I don't know if this is a requirement of the program, but it was completely break if some wise guy enters "Banana".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement has no use because it is not in a while loop. Meaning that if the user enters a number lower than 0 or higher than 501, the code will execute normally. You can use this instead:

```
while (true) {
    if (value < 0 || value > 501) {
    cout << "ERROR! The value you entered is out of range!\n";
    cout << "Please enter a value between 0 and 501\n";
    cin >> value;
    continue;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

This new code will keep asking the user to enter a number between 0 and 501 like you intended.

Your for loop isn't working because you set the value (that the user inputted) to 0 again. So you should initialize a new variable and use it in the for loop. You can use this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        cout << "The even numbers are: " << i << endl;
    }
}
```

So it will do this:

1. See if the i is less than the value that the user inputted, starting with 0.
2. If it is less than the value, it will check if it is an even number (using % 2)
3. If it is an even number, it will print it out.
4. Then it will increment i (increase i by 1) and do this all over again.

Hopefully this helps and don't be afraid to ask questions !

Answer (score 2):

the reason of the broken code is the fact that you are mixing variables in the loop, i.e. the variable that increases and the variable to be compared for going out of the loop:

```
for (value = 0; value > 0 || value < 501; value++)
```

you should have different values for the counter and the condition breaking the loop

```
for (int i = 0; <some logic related to user input>; ++i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditions tells when the loop should stop, there is no value that can make this codition `false` because any integer is either `>0` or `<501`.
You do not need the `value > 0` part of the condition, because you start the loop at `value = 0`. It is not possible that it gets smaller than `0` by incrementing it.

Moreover, you are using `value` as the loop index, but in the first part of the code `value` is the user input that is now lost (overwritten with `0`).

The loop can look like this:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < value; index+=2)
    {                     // ^^^-------------------- the loop stops when this is false
        cout << "The even numbers are: " << index << endl;
    }
```

This loop loops until `index` is bigger or equal to the user entered `value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        {
            if (value % 2 == 0)
            {
            cout << "The even numbers are: " << value << endl;
            }
        }
```

For every number greater than 501 and greater than 0 your condition value > 0 || value < 501 will evaluate to be true.
Make sure you run this loop till the number given by the user.